# Are vedas for the entire humanity?

Tags: vedas, human

Vedas are shruti the highest text in Hinduism, so is the wisdom or knowledge of vedas for the entire humanity. *Or for Indians who are brahmin*.

[*And can a foreigner understand and properly translate vedas in there language*]

Comment: The knowledge in the Vedas applies to all. Vedas say everyone reincarnates, and those who sin go to bad birth, and those who do good go to good birth. The Vedic injunctions are also binding to all. But some people innately understand it better due to ARSa-shakti.

Comment: @DarkKnight Dude, I've told you this 5 times already. Some people UNDERSTAND THE MEANINGS of the Veda better than other people.

Comment: @Ikshvaku okay 

Comment: @Ikshvaku what is ArSa-shakti.

Comment: ARSa means "related to rishis", so it means the energy of rishis that is passed down to their descendants. The Vedas and smritis mention this.